# How can you paste text with indents into Teams on OSX?

Tags: ms-teams

On Mac, pasting indented text from Chrome, PyCharms, etc into a MS Teams chat, removes all leading spaces (in all lines), e.g.:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Original text | Pasted into Teams |

How can I paste the text with indents?

Answer (score 2):

Well well well, isn't Microsoft a box full of surprises? Turns out [this answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/why-does-teams-always-strip-indentation-when-pasting-text/m-p/2901942/highlight/true#M102146) is right!
[image]

Detailed steps:

- Go to the Teams tab in Teams (great name :D) [image]
- Click on New conversation in any Team channel [image]
- Paste your indented text, **matching the style** (Command + Option + Shift + V)! [image]
- *Squint*.... Naaah.... OMG, it worked!! Yup, and now, select all (Command + A) and copy it (Command + C)
- Go to your *chat* and paste it (maybe adding "```" in front to style it) [image]